# include extrenal js file not working

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

I want to include my one external js file into the view which in in the directory `./js/event.js` (root directory)

for this i am using syntax:

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl . '/js/event.js', ['depends' =>[yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```

but the console showing me error as:

> http://localhost/basic/web/js/event.js net::ERR_ABORTED

i am expecting the url like this:

> http://localhost/basic/js/event.js

I am not sure why it is checking js folder into web directory.

Comment: `baseUrl` points to web directory of project.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `Yii::$app->request->BaseUrl . '/js/event.js'` with just `'/basic/js/event.js'` ?

Comment: @InsaneSkull how can i set `baseUrl` to root directory

Comment: Might help : https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/667/yii-2-list-of-path-aliases-available-with-default-basic-and-advanced-app

Comment: @KarloKokkak this is wired @app returns `http://localhost/F:/wamp/www/basic/js/event.js net::ERR_ABORTED`

Comment: Try other aliases.

Comment: @KarloKokkak tried `@app, @web, @webroot` but facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [basePath](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-applications) :

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::$app->basePath . '/js/event.js', ['depends' =>[yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```

To set `baseUrl` to root directory in `web.php`

```
'components' => [
    .
    .
    'request' => [
        'baseUrl' => dirname(__DIR__),
    ],
]
```

Comment: this is what i get `http://localhost/F:/wamp/www/basic/js/event.js` by using `Yii::$app->basePath`

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you to use alias

Try this

```
$this->registerJsFile(Yii::getAlias('@web') . '/js/event.js',
    ['depends' => [\yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
$this->registerJsFile( '@web/js/event.js', ['depends' =>[yii\web\JqueryAsset::className()]]);
```

Reference : http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-client-scripts.html#registering-scripts